Salesforce Boomi connection error. Trying to connect to the sandbox after it was refreshed
Trying to reconnect to Salesforce after a sandbox refreshed.
The test run for SageSalesInvoices to SF Purchases/Donations you are attempting completed with the following errors: Embedded message: Error received executing Salesforce Get; Caused by: Error received for Salesforce Login; Caused by: Error invoking soap operation; Caused by: Unsupported Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Supported ones are: [text/xml]
Entered a new security token and updated the URL and password into Boomi
